DevExpress GridColumn: How to make a DateTime column text-editable, trigger an event on change, and pass row data?
I am working with a DevExpress GridControl (version 16.1), and I have a column for ExecutionTime that is bound to a DateTime property (Model.ExecutionTime). I want to:

Remove the dropdown (calendar) from the editor and make it
text-editable.
Apply a mask (MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff) to enforce a specific format.
Trigger an event after the value is changed and pass the current
row’s data to the ViewModel command.

To achieve this, I used TextEditSettings as the editor for the column and attached dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors to trigger the event. However, I am facing two issues:

When I attach the behaviors inside TextEditSettings, the
EventToCommand is not triggered.
When I attach the behaviors outside the TextEditSettings, the event
triggers, but the CommandParameter (RowData.Row) is null.

Current Implementation:
Here’s the current setup I am using:
Case 1: Behaviors Inside TextEditSettings (Event Not Triggered):
<dxg:GridColumn Header="Ex.Time" FieldName="Model.ExecutionTime" Width="120">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:TextEditSettings
            Mask="MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"
            MaskType="DateTime">
                            <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <dxmvvm:EventToCommand
                    EventName="Validate"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.TradeCommandVm.ExecutionTimeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTrade, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                            </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        </dxe:TextEditSettings>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                </dxg:GridColumn> 

Case 2: Behaviors Outside TextEditSettings (Event Triggered, but ExecutionTime is Null):


<dxg:GridColumn Header="Ex.Time" FieldName="Model.ExecutionTime" Width="120">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                        <dxe:TextEditSettings
            Mask="MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"
            MaskType="DateTime" />
                    </dxg:GridColumn.EditSettings>
                    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <dxmvvm:EventToCommand
            EventName="Validate"
            Command="{Binding DataContext.TradeCommandVm.ExecutionTimeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedTrade, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" >

                        </dxmvvm:EventToCommand>
                    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </dxg:GridColumn>



I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to correctly trigger the event or a similar mechanism within TextEditSettings, or alternative approaches to achieve this functionality. Thank you in advance for your help!

